# Stone backsplash over wood planks

Tags: fireplace, backsplash

I have a fireplace where the wall above is already decorated with wood planks

I was want to do stone backsplash and I was wondering should I remove all the wood planks or can the stones sit on planks ?

All youtube videos assume it is cement behind so I couldnt see if this option is possible

Thank you

Comment: A picture might be helpful.

Comment: No, wood expands and contracts with relative humidity. The stone work would start falling off after a very short time.